# How to find the number of combinations that can be made from n non-unique numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

take a basket of balls labeled 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2.if one is allowed to takeaway 4 balls from the basket, in How many different ways can one do this? is there a formulae to solve this? or do I have to use recursion?

Edit: 1, 1, 2 , 2  and 1, 2, 3, 2 are valid combinations
Edit 2: the order in which one picks them doesnot matter.

Comment: If repeated numbers are not distinct, use the so-called Mississippi formula.

Comment: It depends on whether or not e.g. 1,1,2,2 is the same as 1,2,2,1 or 1,2,1,2

Comment: yes ,1,2,2,1 is the same as 1,2,1,2

Comment: Simplest approach is to note that there are only two repeated elements: three 2's, and two 1's.  So, the number of 2's selected is some element in $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and the number of 1's selected is some element in $\{0,1,2\}$.  Therefore, all that you have to do is manually consider the $(4 \times 3 = 12)$ mutually exclusive cases, one of which is impossible.  That is, you can not select $(3)$ 2's and $(2)$ 1's.  ...see next comment

Comment: If $(a)$ 2's and $(b)$ 1's are selected then $T = [4 - (a+b)]$ elements from $\{3,4,5\}$ must be selected.  So, the enumeration here would be $$\binom{3}{T}.$$ **Edit** : in my previous comment, I overlooked a second (impossible) case : you can't select $(0)$ 2's and $(0)$ 1's.

Comment: agreed , but the problem becomes dependent on T. meaning i have to be mind full of the number of 1's and 2's I am using , and it could get really complicated if I had like 10 (1's) and 12 (2's). isn't there like a general formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, it will get more and more complex as the numbers increase

The best way in these circumstances is to use generating functions

The g.f. of the $1's$ is $x^0 + x^1 + x^2 = 1 + x + x^2$,
the coefficients of $x$ indicating that the $1's$ can be used $0,1,\;or\;2$ times.

In similar vein, that of the $2's$ is $1+x+x^2+x^3$,
and for each of $3,4,5\; is\; 1+x$

If we *multiply* all of them, $(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)$,
the coefficients of x get *added*, so to find how many permissible combos of length $4$ are possible, look for the coefficient of $x^4\;\;$ in $(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x)^3$

The [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coefficient+of+x%5E4+in++%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%29%281%2Bx%29%5E3) is $22$

Comment: Great! this what i was looking for.

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is do you care what the order of the chosen numbers is (i.e. is 1,2,3,2 different to 1,3,2,2)? If so then you use the permutation equation:

#number of permutations = n!/((n-r)!(a!*b!*c!...))

If the order doesn't matter then use the combination equation:

#number of combinations = n!/((n-r)!r!(a!*b!*c!...))

where n is the number of stuff you have (in this case 8), r is the number of things that you choose (in this case 4), and a, b, c, etc are the numbers of repetitions for each of the numbers (that is for your example a=2, b=3, c=1, d=1, e=1 where each letter corresponds to the amount of same numbers).

Comment: yes ,the order doesnot matter but i cannot use ncr/a!*b! , take four balls says  1,2,1,3 and choose four from them, if you were to use this formula then it's you'll end with the answer 1/2. where as the right answer should be 1.